# Import issues Python3: import from package for flask project with api modules

Tags: python-3.x, import, module

I have my code structured as follows:

```
src/
--- api/
--- --- __init__.py
--- example_app.py
```

the init.py contains the following code:

```
from flask_restplus import Api
from api.about_api import api as about_api
from api.types_api import api as types_api

stackl_api = Api(<Snip>)

stackl_api.add_namespace(about_api)
stackl_api.add_namespace(types_api)
```

In example_app.py, I try to do this:

```
    import stackl_api

    app = Flask(__name__)
    blueprint = Blueprint('stackl_api', __name__)
    stackl_api.init_app(blueprint)
    app.register_blueprint(blueprint)
```

But this gives the error

```
 from .api import api                                                                                                                   │
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

if doing "from api import api" it gives "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'api'                                                                                               "

I'm probably forgetting something. Can you  help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In example_app.py, you need to replace

```
from api import api
```

By

```
import api
```